# Error 1064 when creating MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Here is the code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ResetDB;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ResetDB () 
BEGIN
/* reset the database to the initial state where all tables are empty */
     TRUNCATE TABLE Review;
     TRUNCATE TABLE Request;
     TRUNCATE TABLE Friend;
     TRUNCATE TABLE Doctor;
     TRUNCATE TABLE Patient;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

and I get this error when I run it

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //CREATE PROCEDURE ResetDB () 
>       BEGIN

```
delete from Review;
dele' at line 1
```

I don't get why this doesn't work since I am using the same code as suggested in the documentation here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: let me guess, you are trying this on sqlfiddle?

Comment: It is actually important how you execute these queries, e.g. php/mysqli/pdo, via the net connector, ... because the error exists just there. In the mysql client, your code would work fine, that is why your link actually wanted you to execute the code directly in the mysql client, and I suppose you didn't do that. So you should add that information. And btw, this is not the same code as suggested in the documentation. In the documentation, the line containing `delimiter` is the first one. Subtle but (for some applications) sometimes important difference (but probably not the problem here).